# HTML link with media attribute works on service but not on localhost

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying to use the html header link with a media attribute. Weirdly enough, I'm having an issue where it works on *production* but not *localhost*. Since it's just a static page I'm using VSCode Live Server extension to run it locally. I can see that `desktop.css` is present in the network tab and in the sources when I use Chrome dev tools. Images, fonts and the base `styles.css` file all work great, no problems there.

Obviously, I could work around this by using a css media query instead but I'd really like to know what's going on here for my own edification.

Weirdly enough, it ***does*** work when I use the "Toggle device toolbar" thing and view it at desktop width.

#### Relavent Code

From `index.html`

```html
<head>
...
    <link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="./css/desktop.css" media="(min-width: 992px)" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
</head>
```

#### Project Structure

```
project_root
├── README.md
├── css
│   ├── desktop.css
│   └── styles.css
├── fonts
│   └── ...
├── images
│   └── ...
└── index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is the server at fault, try using Apache HTTP server. It seems to happen with other live servers as well. I've seen this happen in other live servers as well, and it seems to just be a limitation of sorts.

I am not even 100% sure if this is the case with the server you are using.